# Что лучше использовать - CSS, img, SVG?

Tags: svg, html, img, css

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, необходимо сделать шапку из прямоугольного треугольника. Через что будет лучше и корректней это реализовать?
Пробовал через img, мне кажется, не удачный вариант, так как качество краёв картинки получалось прерывистом.
Почитал про svg, как понял, там рисуется линия. Можно ли будет в таком случае, к примеру, полученный треугольник залить каким-то цветом и разместить на нём меню, и чтобы всё корректно работало? Или делать это лучше через css посредством border? И если сделать через css, не будет ли невидимая область перекрывать контент, который находится под ней?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через CSS, просто развернув на нужный угол внутренний прямоугольник и обрезав его внешним. Бордер тут ни при чем.

Comment: @knes, отрисовка треугольника с помощью `border`, пожалуй, является классическим способом рисования треугольника средствами CSS. Пример можно посмотреть тут: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: Угу. Но, боюсь, это достаточно сложный способ для случая, когда внутри треугольника будет контент. А если контент все равно ляжет поверх, то почему бы не развернуть прямоугольник?